# Display attachment size of emails stored in a Windows folder using Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook

What I am after is the attachment size of Outlook emails that are saved in a windows share. I can display the name of the attachment but the filesize is incorrect as it should in this instance be 6,357KB

POWERSHELL SCRIPT:

```
$outlook = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\mail\downloads" -Filter *.msg |
    ForEach-Object {
        $msg = $outlook.Session.OpenSharedItem($_.FullName)
        $msg.Attachments | Select FileName, Size
    }
$outlook.Quit()
```

OUTPUT:

FileName                                              Size

---

Electrical Certificate - Domestic EIC_Ref62036711.pdf    0

Hopefully, this is something very simple that I have missed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.size):

> This information may not always be available for attachments. For
> example, on an S/MIME message, the actual attachment sizes are unknown
> until the attachment is extracted. In cases where the attachment size
> cannot be determined, this property returns 0.

You could save the attachments to a temp path and then get the size:

```
function Select-AttachmentSizes {
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        $Message
    )
    if ($Message.Attachments.Count -gt 0) {
        $tempPath = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
        try {
            foreach ($attachment in $Message.Attachments) {
                $size = $attachment.Size
                # if size can't be determined, save to temp file
                if ($size -eq 0) {
                    $attachment.SaveAsFile($tempPath)
                    $size = (Get-Item $tempPath).Length
                }
                # return name and size
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    FileName = $attachment.FileName
                    Size = $size
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            Remove-Item -LiteralPath $tempPath -ea SilentlyContinue
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$msg | Select-AttachmentSizes
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the help, I have tried your suggestion but the script is failing with the following error.
PS C:\Temp> $msg | Select-AttachmentSizes
Select-AttachmentSizes : The term 'Select-AttachmentSizes' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Comment: @Higgsie Then you haven't added the function from my answer yet.